# Сколько максимум памяти может выделить открытая вкладка в Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

На собеседовании у меня задали вопрос про то, сколько памяти максимум может быть выделено под вкладку в браузере. Как это можно узнать?

```js
const blockContainerNode = document.querySelector('.block-container');
const inputNode = document.querySelector('.input');
const btnStartNode = document.querySelector('.btn-start');
const btnEndNode = document.querySelector('.btn-end');

btnStartNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const inputValue = Number(inputNode.value);
  if (!isNaN(inputValue) && inputValue > 0) {
    startAnimation(blockContainerNode, inputValue);
  }
});

btnEndNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  blockContainerNode.textContent = '';
});

function startAnimation(blockContainerNode, quantityBlocks) {
  const blockNodes = new Array(quantityBlocks).fill(0).map((item, i) => {
    const divNode = document.createElement('div');
    divNode.classList.add('block');
    divNode.textContent = i;
    divNode.style.setProperty('--index', i);
    return divNode;
  });
  document.body.style.setProperty('--maxIndex', quantityBlocks);
  blockContainerNode.textContent = '';
  blockContainerNode.append(...blockNodes);
}
```

```css
.block-container {
  --maxIndex: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.block {
  --index: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: anime 2s calc(var(--index) * -0.5s) infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(60deg, 80deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="number" value="1000" placeholder="Количество блоков">
<button class="btn-start" type="button">Начать анимацию</button>
<button class="btn-end" type="button">Удалить</button>
<div class="block-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Попробую угадать. Ответ 4Gb для x64.  Обоснование: одна таба в хроме это один процесс, адресация памяти не позволит этому процессу откушать больше чем 4Gb

Comment: Мне кажется, что ограничение в 2 Гб было характерно да 32-разрядных систем. Там был 2 Гб на пользовательский процесс и 2 гб на систему, как то так. А для 64 разрядных - там можно больше адресовать...

Comment: @UserTest013 где можно почитать про то, что это отдельный процесс. И что за такое понятие процесс, и что он может забирать максимум 4GB?

Comment: [Тут](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models/) написано о процессах. [Тут](https://js9.si.edu/js9/help/memory.html) написано о памяти. @S.H. прав - для 64 разрядных можно больше адресовать, но в хроме действительно ограничение 4Гб.

Comment: @UserTest013 - Круто! может, оформите как ответ?

Comment: @UserTest013 да, отмечу это как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно информации из сайта [js9.si.edu](https://js9.si.edu/js9/help/memory.html) в Хроме х64 ограничение 4Gb на вкладку.

> Browser limitations on per-tab memory are not well documented. The 64-bit Chrome browsers are known to have a 4Gb per-tab memory limit. iOS devices have more stringent limitations: empirical evidence indicates that the iPhone 6 is limited to 645Mb, the iPhone 6s to 1Gb, and the iPhone 7 to 2Gb.

Рискну предположить, что это ограничение связано с тем, что хром для каждой вкладки создает новый процесс. Буду рад, если кто-то дополнит ответ и объяснит почему именно 4Gb.

Comment: Кстати, если несколько вкладок - это один сайт, то они объединяются в один процесс и также могут потреблять максимум 4ГБ оперативной памяти